# Chain length adjustment

Tags: chainring

If I change my 1x chainring from a 44 to a 42, do I need to shorten the chain? If so by how many links?

I am running a 44 with an 11-42 cassette (SRAM Apex1).

Comment: Probably not, and at most two links (the minimum).  Depends on how tight the chain is to start with.

Comment: Just try it out. Shorten only if there is too much slack on the small cog.

Comment: You have a cassette and a derailleur - so any slack will be taken up by that, unless you're already near its limits.

Answer (score 4):

You are reducing the minimum length of chain required by 1 link. (i.e. 22 teeth vs 21 teeth on the front chainring.)

Unless the initial chain sizing was overly generous, you should not notice any significant difference in that small a chainring size change. Since you can only remove 2 links, not just the one link you are changing, you are likely already in 
the appropriate zone for chain length.